# Find files with similar names, delete the oldest, rename the most recent

Tags: shell, files, rename

I have this situation where there's a lot of files with similar names (but they all follow a pattern) in different subfolders

```
file1
file1 (Copy)
/folder1/file2.txt
/folder1/file2 (Copy).txt
/folder1/file3.png
/folder1/file3 (Copy).png
```

Each file is in the same folder of its copy and has the same extension, the difference is that it has `(Copy)` at the end of the name

I want to get all these files and delete the oldest one, then eventually rename the file from, for example, `file1 (Copy)` to `file1` (that is, remove the `(Copy)` suffix) if it needs to be renamed.

I was thinking of using `find` and `mv` but I'm not sure how to tell it to move the most recent one.

Comment: what is the probability that `(Copy)` file would be the recent one?

Comment: the opposite of the probability that the non-copy has been edited.

Comment: As @Jasen pointed out, files have been edited after being copied (in some cases the copy, in others the non-copy). So the probability is > 0% but < 100% if you need i might check and give you a more precise answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Extended **`find`** + **`bash`** solution (also needs the GNU implementation of `stat`):

```
find . -type f -name "* (Copy).*" -exec bash -c 'p="${0%/*}"; bn="${0##*/}"; 
        main_bn="${bn/ (Copy)/}"; 
        if [ -f "$p/$main_bn" ]; then 
           t_copy_file=$(stat -c %Y "$0"); t_main_file=$(stat -c %Y "$p/$main_bn"); 
           if [[ $t_copy_file -gt $t_main_file ]]; then 
               mv "$0" "$p/$main_bn"; 
           else
               rm "$0"; 
           fi; 
        fi' {} \;
```

---

- `p="${0%/*}"` - filepath/path with basename trimmed
- `bn="${0##*/}"` - file's basename
- `main_bn="${bn/ (Copy)/}"` - remove `(Copy)` substring from the basename to obtain the *main/common* basename
- `if [ -f "$p/$main_bn" ]` - if the *main/original* file exists (and is found to be a regular file after symlink resolution)

  - `t_copy_file=$(stat -c %Y "$0")` - get last modification time of found *"copy"* file
  - `t_main_file=$(stat -c %Y "$p/$main_bn")` - get last modification time of *original* file
  - `if [[ $t_copy_file -gt $t_main_file ]]` - if the *"copy"* file is the recent one - move it to the *original* one (make it *original*) with `mv "$0" "$p/$main_bn"`
  - otherwise - the *original* file is the recent one, removing "*copy*" file with `rm "$0"`

---

Or a bit shorter with `-nt` file test operator (`[ new­er­file –nt olderfile ]` - check if `newerfile` was changed more recently than `olderfile`, or if `newerfile` exists and `olderfile` doesn't):

```
find . -type f -name "* (Copy).*" -exec bash -c 'p="${0%/*}"; bn="${0##*/}"; 
        main_bn="${bn/ (Copy)/}"; 
        if [ -f "$p/$main_bn" ]; then 
           if [ "$0" -nt "$p/$main_bn" ]; then 
               mv "$0" "$p/$main_bn"; 
           else
               rm "$0"; 
           fi; 
        fi' {} \;
```

Comment: See the `[ file1 -nt file2 ]` test operator to compare file modification time (available in most shells including bash). It also compares the mtime of the _target_ of symlinks. See `-L` with GNU stat for that.

Comment: You may want to change it to `-exec bash -c 'for file do...' bash {} +` to avoid running one `bash` instance per file, especially considering `bash` is one of the slowest shells to start.

Comment: Thanks, I used the second solution you suggested and then checked files with meld, i can confirm it worked

Comment: Not `for file in "$0"; do`, just `for file do` (loop over the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`... and leave `$0` for what it's meant to be: the name of  the inline script), there's no issue with newline).

Answer (score 4):

It may be easier with `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
for file (./**/?*" (Copy)"*(ND.)) {
  base=$file:h/${${file:t}/" (Copy)"}}
  [[ ! -f $base || -L $base ]] ||
    if [ $file -nt $base ]; then
      mv $file $base
    else
      rm -f $file
    fi
}
```

You might want to check that there's no `file (Copy) (Copy).txt` files first.

- `**/`: any level of subdirectory
- `N`: *nullglob* expand to nothing if there's no match instead of erroring out
- `D`: include hidden files (`D`ot files) and descending into hidden directories.
- `.`: only include *regular* files (no directory, fifo, device, symlink...)
- `$file:h`: *head* of the file (directory part), like in `csh`
- `$file:t`: *tail* (filename part)
- `${var/pattern/replacement}`, here with no replacement
- `[[ ! -f $base || -L $base ]] ||...` skip non-regular files or symlinks (even if they point to regular files) as a safeguard.
- `[ $file -nt $base ]`: returns true if `$file` was last modified *after* `$base` (or `$base` is not accessible, we should not happen following the check above).